# Given a Taylor approximation and an interval, how do we find the maximum error possible?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Given an approximation of **sin**($x$) with a Maclaurin  polynomial with degree $5$,  ($x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}$), and given and interval $-0.3 < x < 0.3$, how do we find the maximum error?

Comment: Since the Taylor series is alternating the maximum error is less than the magnitude of the next term in the series. $\frac {0.3^7}{7!}$

Comment: Alright, I think I understand. But would you mind elaborating a bit more? Like, what steps should I fallow to get there and what do they mean?

Answer (score 1):

We can refer to Taylor's series with Lagrange remainder, that is

$$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+f''(0)\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+f^{(n)}(0)\frac{x^n}{n!}+R_n$$

with

$$R_n=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

The series is alternating, i.e.

i.e. $s = \sum_\limits{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k a_k$ and  $0<a_{k+1}<a_k$

Each successive term in the series takes you from the positive side of s to the negative side.

That is, if $s_n$ is the partial sum of the first $n$ terms and $s_n > s$ then $s_{n+1} < s$

This implies $\epsilon = |s-s_n| < a_{n+1}$

It is a special case, and is generally more precise than the typical result from the remainder theorem.